# Laravel filename is not saving properly in database while uploading

Tags: php, laravel

I want to upload and save the file if the request has the avatar field. But when I upload, the file is uploading properly in the digital ocean spaces with the generated filename. But in my database, it is saving like - C:\Users\debar\AppData\Local\Temp\php29DC.tmp

```
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'string',
            'mobile' => 'numeric|nullable',
            'email' => 'email|nullable',
            'bio' => 'string|nullable',
            'school' => 'string|nullable',
            'college' => 'string|nullable',
            'country_id' => 'integer|nullable',
            'state_id' => 'integer|nullable',
            'city_id' => 'integer|nullable',
            'avatar' => 'file|nullable'
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            $errors = ['validation_error' => $validator->errors()];
            return response()->json($errors, 400);
        }

        if($request->has('avatar')){            
            $extension = $request->file('avatar')->extension();
            $mimeType = $request->file('avatar')->getMimeType();
            $fileName = time().'.'.$extension;
            
            Storage::disk('do_spaces')->putFileAs('doctor-profile', $request->file('avatar'), $fileName);

            $request->avatar = $fileName;

        }

        $doctor = Auth::guard('doctor_api')->user();

        $doctor->update($request->all());

        return $doctor;
```

When I dd($request->avatar);

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#380
  -test: false
  -originalName: "dummy-girl.jpg"
  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "C:\Users\debar\AppData\Local\Temp"
  filename: "phpCD78.tmp"
  basename: "phpCD78.tmp"
  pathname: "C:\Users\debar\AppData\Local\Temp\phpCD78.tmp"
  extension: "tmp"
  realPath: "C:\Users\debar\AppData\Local\Temp\phpCD78.tmp"
  aTime: 2020-10-16 15:45:08
  mTime: 2020-10-16 15:45:08
  cTime: 2020-10-16 15:45:08
  inode: 19140298416425963
  size: 10227
  perms: 0100666
  owner: 0
  group: 0
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
  linkTarget: "C:\Users\debar\AppData\Local\Temp\phpCD78.tmp"
}
```

Comment: when you are saving your file in digital ocean space at that time you are creating a new file name "$fileName" while when it's updating in DB at that time you've put your request param to update change your request param before the update in DB and put your new filename there

Comment: I tried like this -  $request->merge([ 'avatar' => 'abc' ]);
but still not working

Comment: dd your $request

Comment: Add this line before the `update` method : `$request->merge(['avatar' => $fileName ?? NULL]);`

Comment: I tried that but not working. I have updated the question with dd($request->avatar)

Comment: Can you try:

$path = $request->file('avatar')->storeAs(
    'avatars',
    $request->user()->id,
    'do_spaces'
);